# Error Logging in Django and Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, logging

I want logging in Django and Gunicorn, when I get error.
I study with TDD with Python, http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch17.html#_setting_up_logging

this is my code.
/etc/init/gunicorn-superlists-staging.mysite.com.conf

```
description "Gunicorn server for superlists-staging.mysite.com"

start on net-device-up
stop on shutdown

respawn

setuid junsu
chdir /home/junsu/sites/superlists-staging.mysite.com/source

exec ../virtualenv/bin/gunicorn \
    --bind unix:/tmp/superlists-staging.mysite.com.socket \
    --access-logfile ../access.log \
    --error-logfile ../error.log \
    superlists.wsgi:application
```

accounts/authentication.py

```
import requests
import logging
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

PERSONA_VERIFY_URL = 'https://verifier.login.persona.org/verify'
DOMAIN = 'localhost'

class PersonaAuthenticationBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, assertion):
        logging.warning('authenticate function')
        response = requests.post(
            PERSONA_VERIFY_URL,
            data={'assertion': assertion, 'audience': settings.DOMAIN}
        )
        logging.warning('got response form persona')
        logging.warning(response.content.decode())
        if response.ok and response.json()['status'] == 'okay':
            email = response.json()['email']
            try:
                return User.objects.get(email=email)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return User.objects.create(email=email)

    def get_user(self, email):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

superlists/settings.py

```
[....]
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_logger': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
    },
    'root': {'level': 'INFO'},
}
```

my "error.log" just log this.

```
[2016-02-08 14:42:56 +0900] [3355] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/tmp/superlists-staging.mysite.com.socket (3355)
[2016-02-08 14:42:56 +0900] [3355] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-02-08 14:42:56 +0900] [3359] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3359
[2016-02-08 14:58:22 +0900] [3355] [INFO] Handling signal: term
[2016-02-08 14:58:22 +0900] [3355] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2016-02-08 14:58:22 +0900] [3470] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.3
[2016-02-08 14:58:22 +0900] [3470] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/tmp/superlists-staging.mysite.com.socket (3470)
[2016-02-08 14:58:22 +0900] [3470] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-02-08 14:58:22 +0900] [3474] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3474
```

I want see error loging, What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr there's nothing wrong with your code**

It seems you've followed the linked tutorial correctly, and would probably find your log files in the `/home/junsu/sites/superlists-staging.mysite.com/` dir.

Regardless, there are a few points to address in your question, I'll try to do that.

#### Loggers and handlers

The settings module you reference above sets up a single logging handler `console` ([StreamHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler)), and a single `django` logger which can use that handler.

The `root` logger does not define any handlers, and "django" will log anything to `stderr`, and only for level INFO and above. I ran a quick test, and the `root` logger also has a `StreamHandler` defined by default.

Your `authentication.py` module currently calls [`logging.warning` which logs to `root` logger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.warning) (i.e it does `logger = logging.getLogger(); logger.warning('stuff')`). However, you may want to define a more specific handler to easier locate the log of your module. This is explained [in this section of the referenced tutorial](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch17.html#_using_hierarchical_logging_config).

#### Gunicorn redirects stderr by default

It seems [by default is set up to capture the `stderr` stream](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1020#issuecomment-97441853), which you currently redirect to a log file. However, my suggestion is to use your daemonizing app (seems like you're using `upstart`) to log the stderr/out.

#### Upstart logging

As explained in [gunicorn docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#upstart), configuring `upstart` is pretty simple.

If you remove the `--error-logfile` option in your `/etc/init/gunicorn-superlists-staging.mysite.com.conf` config, gunicorn will default to logging it's output to `stderr` which can then be captured by upstart in whatever manner you prefer.

If you are using upstart 1.7 or greater, [stdout/err capturing should be enabled by default](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#console). If, however, you use an earlier version of upstart, my suggestion is to add [a `console log` option in your config](https://serverfault.com/a/659185/58545) and all output (stdout/stderr) will simply be logged to (I assume) `/var/log/upstart/gunicorn-superlists-staging.mysite.com.log`

Comment: Thanks!, I saw the upstart log file. I think, it's very useful. but I can't resolve error.log file problem. I will continue once the tutorial.

Answer (score 17):

For those searching for **error logs**  for (**nginx + gunicorn + django**) setup:

Simply use these 
(Some commands also specific to where your socket files are located)

- Check the Nginx process logs by typing: `sudo journalctl -u nginx`
- Check the Nginx access logs by typing: `sudo less /var/log/nginx/access.log`
- Check the Nginx error logs by typing: `sudo less /var/log/nginx/error.log`
- Check the **Gunicorn application** logs by typing: `sudo journalctl -u gunicorn`
- Check the Gunicorn socket logs by typing: `sudo journalctl -u gunicorn.socket`

[Reference](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04#further-troubleshooting)

Comment: Good point for checking all sorts of logs. It helped me. In my case, I finally found the error from Ubunut's system logs. Run `dmesg`.