# Deploy Flask with Gunicorn and NginX Gunicorn Error "Failed with result 'exit-code'"

Tags: nginx, flask, deployment, server, gunicorn

I'm following this YouTube Tutorial to setup my Server with Flask and Nginx: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2WA-A67Bks&t=360s

Right now I'm at the Gunicorn part. I tried to start following commands:

```
systemctl daemon-reload

systemctl start index

systemctl enable index

systemctl status index
```

But it doesn't work. The Error Message looks like this:

```
● index.service - Gunicorn instance to serve One
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/index.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-12-01 18:14:40 CET; 8s ago
 Main PID: 24620 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Dez 01 18:14:40 h2912959.stratoserver.net systemd[1]: Started Gunicorn instance to serve One.
Dez 01 18:14:40 h2912959.stratoserver.net systemd[24620]: index.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Dez 01 18:14:40 h2912959.stratoserver.net systemd[24620]: index.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /var/www/html/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory
Dez 01 18:14:40 h2912959.stratoserver.net systemd[1]: index.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Dez 01 18:14:40 h2912959.stratoserver.net systemd[1]: index.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

My index.service file looks like that:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve One
After=network.target

[Service]
User=daemon
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html
Environment="PATH=/var/www/html/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/var/www/html/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Can please help anyone?

Comment: I did this recently and debugging the whole process is a pain. This answer is a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60401132/7975785