# Gunicorn does not display updated logs. But once I restart gunicorn service it shows all the logs

Tags: django, nginx, server, gunicorn

I went through multiple stack overflow questions and blogs for this issue and tried the answers available but no success.
Below is my gunicorn service socket and ngnix config settings. Please help me out have been stuck on this for almost 1 week.

Version of packages
Django==2.2.7
gunicorn==20.1.0
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

```
gunicorn.socket
[Unit]
Description=IPU socket
[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/IPU.sock
[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

gunicorn.service
[Unit]
Description=IPU daemon
Requires=IPU.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu

WorkingDirectory=/project/path

ExecStart=/../../venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --bind unix:/run/IPU.sock \
          --capture-output \
          --workers 4 \
          --worker-class gevent \
          --worker-connections 1000 \
          --timeout 300 \
          --access-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/access.log \
          --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/error.log \
          IPU.wsgi:application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

nginx.conf
server {
    listen 9000 default_server;
    listen [::]:9000 default_server;
    server_name ip_address;
    rewrite_log on;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /IPU/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/IPU.sock:/;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you watch you logs?

Comment: I look for the logs in error.log file i have created. And i also checked using the command sudo journalctl -u gunicorn.service but cannot see the updated log. What i want is the print statements and other instructions which we see in django console to be displyaed in  gunicorn log file. @oruchkin

Comment: @Parth are you talking about nginx `error.log` or systemd error log?

Comment: i am talking about the print statements we see in gunicorn log when we hit the django api. should i share my error log ? @user973254

Comment: @Parth I'm trying to understand if we talking about nginx or Django problem

Comment: There's no issue with nginx log. I cannot see the django logs on server

Comment: @user973254 can you help me out sir

Comment: @Parth have you checked this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35263449/error-logging-in-django-and-gunicorn

Comment: @user973254 yes sir i went through this.